# Merging multiple databases with non-repeating condition for one table and concatenate another table

Tags: python, sql, database

I have two databases, let's call them DB1 and DB2.

DB1 and DB2 have the same tables, but with different information.

Long story short there is one table of 'Definitions' and another of 'Data' in each one of them.

'Data' is made o purely raw data, and it is specified by and DefID that I can use to link to the 'Definition' table and find out what it means.

So at this point what I need to do is to concatenate 'Data' and at the same time merge 'Definitions', that is I will not have repeated strings in 'Definitions' but I will not overwrite anything in 'Data' even if there are repeated values.

Would anyone help me figure out what SQL command I could use to do that in pyodbc library?

For concatenating the data I think that:

```
INSERT TO DB1.Data (DefId,Val1,Val2,Val3) VALUES (defidx,val1x,val2x,val3x)
```

In a loop, where defidx,val1x, val2x and val3x are values fetched from the other table, should do the job. I don't know if I should worry about the position of the cursor being at the end of the table (maybe??). Another problem with this would be that the tables have relationships with other tables in the data, I would have to deal with that too

For merging with no repetitions ('Definitions') I have no idea where to begin.

EDIT:
To show you better what I want

BEFORE:

DB1:

```
'Definitions'
Id  Def   
1   'Def1'
2   'Def2'
3   'Def3'
```

```
'Data'
Id DefId Val1  Val2  Val3
1  1     23    0     11
2  1     34    0     11
3  1     213   0     11
4  2     120   1     9
5  3     32    3     15
6  2     211   1     9
```

DB2:

```
'Definitions'
Id  Def   
1   'Def1'
2   'Def2'
3   'Def4'
```

```
'Data'
Id DefId Val1  Val2  Val3
1  1     3     0     11
2  1     4     0     11
3  2     2     1     9
4  3     1     3     15
```

AFTER:

DB1

(or other DB created, say DB3)

```
'Definitions'
Id  Def   
1   'Def1'
2   'Def2'
3   'Def3'

4   'Def4'
```

```
'Data'
Id DefId Val1  Val2  Val3
1  1     23    0     11
2  1     34    0     11
3  1     213   0     11
4  2     120   1     9
5  3     32    3     15
6  2     211   1     9

7  1     3     0     11
8  1     4     0     11
9  2     2     1     9
10 3     1     3     15
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want, as tabular text.

Comment: Done! I've been trying this morning to copy info from one database and insert into another, that wont work "You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table.." since I'm not concerned about this related data in a third table, I will just copy info from both databases and create a third one, maybe that will work just fine !